# How to see the connectivity status for each device directly from UI in zenoss monitoring

Tags: snmp, zenoss

This question is related to zenoss monitoring.

I want to know how to see the connectivity status for each device directly from zenoss UI page instead from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Open your device and *DEVICE STATUS* is result of last Zenoss "ping" check. Or you can run *"Commands"* -> *"ping"*, if it's available:
[image: Zenoss Ping]